# append to path for all users in windows programmatically.

Tags: windows, powershell, path, chef-infra, chef-solo

I am appending to windows path in chef but it only reflects for administrator (uses to administrator to append to path)

```
# append dnx.exe to %PATH%
windows_path '%USERPROFILE%\\.dnx\\runtimes\\dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1\\bin' do
  action :add
end
```

Is there a command to append to path and make it available for all users of windows programmatically ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have experience with Chef, but the canonical way to add something to the PATH environment variable for all users is to append it to the variable in the machine environment rather than the user environment. In PowerShell you do it like this:

```
$path = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'Machine')
$path += ';%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin'
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $path, 'Machine')
```

If you want to merge that into a single statement it'd look somewhat like this:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', ([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'Machine') + ';%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin'), 'Machine')
```

However, you may not want to simply append to the variable, as that might keep adding the path to the variable over and over again. To avoid that you could do something like this:

```
$dir  = '%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin'
$path = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'Machine') -split ';' |
        Where-Object { $_ -ne $dir }
$path += $dir
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', ($path -join ';'), 'Machine')
```

---

**Edit:** I just realized that `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` can't be used in your case. While the method will set the variable to the string you pass into it, that string will be stored as a `REG_SZ` value in the registry. Which will prevent variables inside the string (like `%USERPROFILE%`) from being expanded when the path is looked up, kinda making the whole thing pointless.

To avoid this pitfall you must ensure that the path is stored in a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value, e.g. like this:

```
$regkey = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regkey -Name 'Path' -Value $path -Type ExpandString
```

Comment: perfect, just what I wanted!

Comment: Also, whats the use of $newpath ? I dont see it being used or generated anywhere. keeps adding blank values to $path

Comment: did you mean , $path += $dir

Comment: Yes, I did. Decided to rename the variable just before posting, but obviously missed one occurrence.

Comment: This works well to preserve the new variables which are added. But it should be noted that original variables that were in Path are lost when reading it from the registry into `$path`. The original `%SystemRoot%` becomes hardcoded into `C:\Windows` (or whatever it is on your system), etc. Only the ones you add are preserved.